# 2 files found with path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libfbjni.so'. If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

I am trying to build one of my react native projects, but for some android jniLibs and CMake issues.
I am unable to do that

this is my build output,

Caused by: com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: 2 files found with path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libfbjni.so'.
If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see
https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets
at com.android.builder.merge.StreamMergeAlgorithms.lambda$acceptOnlyOne$2(StreamMergeAlgorithms.java:75)
at com.android.builder.merge.StreamMergeAlgorithms.lambda$select$3(StreamMergeAlgorithms.java:95)
at com.android.builder.merge.IncrementalFileMergerOutputs$1.create(IncrementalFileMergerOutputs.java:88)
... 34 more

this dependency I am using

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"

    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.1'

    implementation "com.pdftron:pdftron:9.2.2-beta07"
    implementation "com.pdftron:tools:9.2.2-beta07"
    implementation "com.pdftron:collab:9.2.2-beta07"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out that these files that logcat show what the parent belongs if you find out what library or dependency  cause this then try this solution,

As I also faced this problem and for me, it is because the **library** I using in my project contains **XYZ** dependency and in my actual project i'm implementing **same or similar** dependency that's because I got this error then I tried this solution and it fixed my solution

```
implementation('com.xyz.xyz:XYZ:1.2.18') {
    exclude group: 'com.abc', module: 'ABC'
}
```

and then implement fresh one

```
    implementation 'com.abc.ABC:ABC:1.1.22'
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: can you describe a little bit more,means which file and where we add this code

Comment: In gradle file or where you manage your dependency

Comment: I updated my question, with extra information regarding dependency